# Laravel Google Analytics Event tracking

Tags: laravel, google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I use Laravel-GAMP Package for google analytics event tracking. But the problem is even though my config is right and also I check firewall and cors. It didn't appear any data in my google analytics.
here the packgae I used : https://github.com/irazasyed/laravel-gamp
Below is my screenshot.
[image]

For this I use this code

```
$gamp = GAMP::setClientId( '123456' );
$gamp->setDocumentPath( '/page' );
$gamp->sendPageview();
```

For Event tracking, I use this code

```
$uuid = (string) Str::uuid();
$gamp = GAMP::setClientId( $uuid );
$gamp->setEventCategory('Blog Post')
->setEventAction('Create')
->setEventLabel('Using GAMP In Laravel')
->sendEvent();
```

I test with google analytics extension.
It says I coundn't connect.
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code not a picture of your code.

Comment: i edited, is that ok?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the realtime reports make sure there is hits showing there. If their are wait 24-48 hours and they should show up in the standard reports.
2. If hits are not appearing in the realtime reports then go to the admin section of your google analytics account and make sure you shutff bot filtering.
3. I'm not a larval dev but you should also remember that anything you send to the debugEndpoint will not be logged to google analytics its just for debugging and the scheme should be https i believe but im not 100% sure.

[Measurement protocol documentation.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide?hl=en)

Comment: i check in real time, but not a single data shows up. what others do I need to consider.

Comment: The second option and disable bot filtering.

Comment: has google analytic already excluded. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9888366

Comment: what the reasons can be can't connect? do u have any thoughts

Comment: Im not sure what you are trying to connect to.   You understand that tag assistant is not google analytics measurement protocol right?   And its not going to be detected as true google analytics tagging.

Comment: Google analytics tagging use measurement protocol, too. I'm just trying to connect with my tracking id. But if I use javascript code, it works. Just not in PHP code. I'm wondering what I need others to make the connection with google analytics.

Comment: The measurement protocol isnt for tagging,  the measurement protocol is for sending hits directly to google analytics.    This bypasses everything and just sends pure hits.   If you post this up on a website some where nothings going to detect that its tagging becouse its not tagging.  If you want to add tagging on your site then do it properly https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs

Comment: My purpose is to send from the backend, not from the frontend like using javascript.

Comment: then you need to use the measurement protocol